# How to return dapper dynamic query when asp.net core api method type is IEnumerable<dynamic> and without newtonsoft.json reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dapper

I hope return dapper dynamic query when asp.net core api method type is IEnumerable and without newtonsoft.json reference.

If asp.net core api method type is `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and using `Dapper dynamic query` system'll throw exception `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<GetEnumerator>d__9' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ServerApp.Helper;
using Dapper;

namespace ServerApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ShDjController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get()
        {
           using(var cn = DB.GetConnection()){
               return cn.Query(@"select * from table");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I know it can be used `NewtonSoft.Json` to serialize data to json string dealing this problem , but it need more reference, like below code :

```
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
           using(var cn = DB.GetConnection()){
               return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cn.Query(@"select * from table "));
           }
        }
```

or

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Full error log :

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<GetEnumerator>d__9' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Csproj

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Table Demo Script :

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table
    ([col1] int, [col2] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table
    ([col1], [col2])
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (3, 4),
    (5, 6)
;
```

Comment: can you also share what your query might be returning from database?

Comment: @zetawars i updated script

Comment: Why are you working with IEnumerable<dynamic> here? U trying to build some "get anything" endpoint?

Comment: because it doesn't need any convert/cast to dapper dynamic query

Comment: honestly, everything works better with a type; I'd use `var data = Query<MyType>(...).AsList();` here, and pass *that* to my JSON serializer. It'll work better *in every way* (context: I wrote Dapper)

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦ , yes,best way is strong type,but sometime i want to use dynamic type for changing frequently project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i have used the Dapper ORM recently, and this worked perfectly for me

```
public string Index()
{
     using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Db;Integrated Security=True"))
     {
         return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( cn.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Accounts.[User]"));
     }
}
```

I didn't even need to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Index()
{
     using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=InstgramWeb;Integrated Security=True"))
     {
           return  cn.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Accounts.[User]");
     }
}
```

Whatever error you are having might relate to something else. maybe a specific column? ( Or it could be a version issue ?)

EDIT:
It works for .NET Core 3.1 and not for .NET Core 3.0. Updating the version could solve the issue or otherwise we could use Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Yes , Newtonsoft.Json can slove this problem, but i don't want this reference.

Comment: i use `netcoreapp3.0` version,could i get your version? or u added `AddNewtonsoftJson` at service?

Comment: 3.1. going to switch 3.0 (to check)

Comment: what is dapper version you are using? package Name ?

Comment: `<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35" />`

Comment: is this done automatically somewhere? "services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();" I haven't done that either. you know what? just create a new project and test it there.it should be working

Comment: I got the point. asp.net core 3.1 have this feature on convert IEnumerable<dynamic>,could u update the answer? i'll mark it answer.

Comment: is your project asp.net core mvc or asp.net core api?

Comment: well, it was an mvc project.

Comment: maybe asp.net core mvc default implement dynamic convert

Comment: maybe, I am going to check that. update here later on. Thanks